# Use multiple Index search in multiple fields in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

This is my search query. Here I am trying to search inside two different fields of two different index but it is giving result from one index only

```
array:2 [
  "index" => "items-123-*,asso-456-*"
  "body" => array:1 [
    "query" => array:1 [
       "bool" => array:1 [
         "should" => array:2 [
            0 => array:1 [
             "match" => array:1 [
               "title" => "Civics"
             ]
           ]
         1 => array:1 [
           "match" => array:1 [
              "type" => "matchOf"
          ]
        ]
     ]
   ]
 ]
]
]
```

I tried below way but not working

```
    array:1 [
  "body" => array:1 [
    "query" => array:1 [
      "bool" => array:1 [
        "should" => array:2 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "term" => array:1 [
              "_index" => "items-123-123"
            ]
            "match_phrase" => array:1 [
              "title" => "Civics"
            ]
          ]
          1 => array:2 [
            "term" => array:1 [
              "_index" => "cfassociations-345-*"
            ]
            "match_phrase" => array:1 [
              "type" => "matchOf"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you please add current response and expected response. Also, document which is not coming in response.

Comment: I am getting only from asso index, not from item index @SagarPatel

Comment: Can you please add document which are not coming ? Also, it will be great if you can post actual Elasticsearch DSL query.

Comment: if I pass "index" => "items-123-*, asso-456-*" with space after comma, it return data from items-123-* and "index" => "items-123-*,asso-456-*"  without space after command, it return data from asso-456-* @SagarPatel

Comment: @SagarPatel any data required?

Comment: I have checked in Kibana and it should give you result when you give without space for both the index. I am not sure how it worked in PHP as i have mostly workaround java.

Comment: Can you try addind + wildcard:  "+items-123-*,+asso-456-*"

Comment: how to add it? I have tried to change "match" to wildcard but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `alias` to search for multiple index. For index `items-123-*`

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "items-123-*",
        "alias": "my-new-index"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And for index `asso-456-*`

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "asso-456-*",
        "alias": "my-new-index"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can search by using the alias name `my-new-index`.

Comment: Issue is not related to query, it's multi indexes are not working

Comment: You can create an alias for all your index and search using alias.